# Pairing versions of CUDA and cuDNN

Tags: cuda, versions

The cuDNN [archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) specifies a CUDA version for every cuDNN version. For example, there are 4 types of cuDNN v7.5.1 for CUDA 9.0, 9.2, 10.0 and 10.1. Are these pairings strict? Can I for example, use the cuDNN v7.5.1 designed for CUDA 10.1, with CUDA 10.2 instead of CUDA 10.1?

Comment: Why do you want to? Generally just using the latest pair compatible with your system (driver + GPU) works fine.

Comment: I already have CUDA 10.2 installed. A program I want to run recommends using the CUDA 10.1 + cuDNN v7.5.1 combination. I am having issues installing CUDA 10.1. Hence, I was wondering if I could just use cuDNN v7.5.1 (designed for CUDA 10.1) instead with the existing CUDA 10.2 that I have installed.

Comment: It might work, as those versions are pretty close. It is probobly easier to just install CUDA 10.1 and then use cuDNN v7.5.1 which is known to work, though